# Selenium with python and try to send keys with the image in the website but it got multiple images were uploaded

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I use selenium with python and try to send keys with the images in the website but it got multiple images were uploaded on the website.

Here is my code.

```
for pic in datahandled['post_images']:
        upload = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="step_media_photo"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/input')))                                                                             
        upload.send_keys(os.path.abspath(pic))
```

This loop is working just fine. If I try to print the counter and print pic(It's the image path) is also fine. But in the website I got the multiple upload like when the first loop start the image was uploaded fine. But when it come to the second loop the 2 images(image 1 and 2) were uploaded then the third 3 images(image 1, 2 and 3) were uploaded. Please kindly advise me.

Comment: add `upload.clear()` below `upload` variable

Comment: I got error element not "selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable"

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to loop in finding an element, if you get it once then it's there, and also improves your script time performance. Second, after you use an input it's a better practice to clear it, to not find yourself in situations like the above.

```
upload = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="step_media_photo"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/input'))) 
for pic in datahandled['post_images']:                                                                            
    upload.send_keys(os.path.abspath(pic))
    upload.clear()
```

Comment: I still got the error `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable` I look like from the upload.clear function.

Comment: can you paste the URL you are trying to access?